# Why can the parameter of map be a string?

Tags: python, map-function

```
from functools import reduce

def fn(x, y):
     return x * 10 + y

def char2num(s):
     return {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9}[s]

a=reduce(fn, map(char2num, '13579'))
print(a)
```

Why can the attribute '13579' of map be a string, shouldn't it be a list?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

Comment: The same reason you can write `for x in '13579':`

Comment: Strings and lists are sequences.  The Python `map()` function (as well as `filter()` and `reduce()` and many others) operate on any sequence.  In fact they operate over any "iterable."  *Sequences* in Python are also "iterable" types.  (Generators are the other major type of iterable which are NOT sequences).

Answer (score 1):

`map` takes a *function* and a *sequence*. Strings are sequences as well. You can also iterate it:

> map(...):   map(function, sequence[, sequence, ...]) -> list

```
>>> s = 'string'
>>> for i in s:
    print i

s
t
r
i
n
g
```

Comment: Technically `map()` takes a function (callable) and an *iterable*.  Sequences happen to be iterable.

Answer (score 0):

In Python a string is a list of chars. Thats why you can loop (or use map) over a string and then work on every char separately inside the loop.

You can find more infos here http://www.openbookproject.net/books/bpp4awd/ch03.html

Comment: Not sure if you're just being informal, but a string is not a list of chars where "list" is interpreted as a Python list.

Comment: Informal, if needed I could cute the code where and how the itterator that map needs is implemented, but I didn't feel this amount of abstraction would benefit to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

### From the [`documentation`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

The documentation describes the `map()` `function` as taking a `function` which is applied to each `item` in an  **`iterable`**:

> map(function, iterable, …)
>
> Apply function to every item of iterable and return a list of the results.

And since `Python` `strings` are `iterables`, just like `lists`, you can pass them into `map()` as you can `lists`. We can show that they are `iterables` by simply `iterating` over them in a `for-loop`:

```
for i in "1234":
   print(i)
```

which will `print` out:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Hopefully this helps you to see why `strings` can be passed into `map`.